# Using Hiera to set global variables

Tags: puppet

I'd like to set a value used repeatedly by several classes and resources from Hiera. In other words, set a global parameter through Hiera. So, in the appropriate yaml file, I have:

```
myvarr: 'foo'
```

Then, in the manifests, I tried:

```
if $myvar == 'foo'
```

as well as

```
if $::myvar == 'foo'
```

to no avail. How is this done? Looking at the Puppet docs didn't help much, all I saw was class based examples.

Comment: try with $var = hiera('myavr')

Comment: @c4f4t0r yup - that's what I needed. If you post that as an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `puppet 3`, puppet does `hiera` automatic lookup, but if you have many modules or classes, doing automatic lookup for every module or class variable increase the catalog compilation time, for disable automatic lookup

```
data_binding_terminus = none
```

I prefer make explicit call, only where I need to get data from `hiera`:

```
$var = hiera('foo')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hiera injects the variable into a class. So you need to define a class my class and in your hiera use myclass::var: foo . This will make var=foo inside myclass.

Also, hiera should be used for overwriting default values, not set defaults.